# using GNU Parted to display complete HDD data

Tags: linux, partition

How do I use parted command to show free space in my hard disk?

cfdisk shows free space while `parted -l` doesnt show any free and unallocated space.

Answer (score 3):

```
graeme@graeme-laptop:~$ sudo parted -l /dev/sda
Model: ATA ST9250827AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system     Flags
 2      1049kB  250GB  250GB  primary   ext4            boot
 1      250GB   250GB  537MB  extended
 5      250GB   250GB  537MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

df -h
to show free and used space for every mounted partition

Comment: i want to know the size of unallocated space on the harddisk.
df -h wont work here.

Comment: Ah ok...so just a sfdisk -l <dev> or even a fdisk -l <dev>

Answer (score 0):

(parted) print

```
Disk geometry for /dev/hda: 0.000-2445.679 megabytes
          Disk label type: msdos
          Minor    Start       End     Type      Filesystem  Flags
          1          0.031    945.000  primary   fat32       boot, lba
          2        945.000   2358.562  primary   ext2
          3       2358.562   2445.187  primary   linux-swap
```

(parted) print 1

```
          Minor: 1
          Flags: boot, lba
          File System: fat32
          Size:            945.000Mb (0%)
          Minimum size:     84.361Mb (0%)
          Maximum size:   2445.679Mb (100%)
```

Comment: Model: ATA WDC WD800JD-75MS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  32.2GB  32.2GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 2      32.2GB  53.7GB  21.5GB  extended                  lba
 5      32.2GB  36.4GB  4162MB  logical   ntfs
 6      36.4GB  53.7GB  17.3GB  logical   ext2
 3      53.7GB  79.0GB  25.3GB  primary   ext3
 4      79.0GB  80.0GB  1012MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)

this is the output of parted -l.
i need to know the unallocated space on my harddrive.